Inconsistent Texture Rendering in Raycasting Due to Intersection Calculations
I'm working on a raycasting engine where I'm encountering an issue with inconsistent texture rendering. When rays hit consecutive walls of the same texture (e.g., 1 1 1 in the map), some rays incorrectly switch to a different texture at the intersections.
Here's a snippet of my code where I calculate the ray distances and intersections:
    // calculate rays' distances
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RAYS; i++) {
        rayangle = normalizeAngle(rayangle);
        ray[i].angle = rayangle;
        set_ray_angle(&ray[i]);

        // find horizontal and vertical intersection points
        t_point horInter = hor_intersection_distance(ray[i], player);
        t_point verInter = ver_intersection_distance(ray[i], player);

        // find the closest intersection point
        ray[i].intersection = min_point(horInter, verInter, player);

        // set distance
        ray[i].distance = distance(player, min);
        
        if (equal_points(min, verInter))
        {
            // print VER in green
            printf(GREEN"horx: %.2f hory: %.2f verx: %.2f very: %.2f difference: (%f) => VER\n\n"RESET, horInter.x, horInter.y, verInter.x, verInter.y, ray[i].distance);
            ray[i].wasHitVertical = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // print HOR in red
            printf(RED"horx: %.2f hory: %.2f verx: %.2f very: %.2f difference: (%f) => HOR\n\n"RESET, horInter.x, horInter.y, verInter.x, verInter.y, ray[i].distance);
            ray[i].wasHitVertical = false;
        }


        // increment angle
        rayangle += angle_inc;
    }

For example, sometimes, at the intersections of these walls, rays closer to the intersection identify a vertical intersection (while the rest is horizontal), causing the wrong texture to render. Here is a sample of the output, showing the intersections and the type identified:
=======> diffeence : -2.016977
horx: 317.81 hory: 319.00 verx: 320.00 very: 318.80 difference: (110.849030) => HOR

=======> diffeence : -1.672793
horx: 318.11 hory: 319.00 verx: 320.00 very: 318.97 difference: (111.112481) => HOR

=======> diffeence : -1.327457
horx: 318.41 hory: 319.00 verx: 320.00 very: 319.14 difference: (111.377395) => HOR

=======> diffeence : -0.980956
horx: 318.72 hory: 319.00 verx: 320.00 very: 319.30 difference: (111.643781) => HOR

=======> diffeence : -0.633276
horx: 319.02 hory: 319.00 verx: 320.00 very: 319.47 difference: (111.911651) => HOR

=======> diffeence : -0.284406
horx: 319.33 hory: 319.00 verx: 320.00 very: 319.64 difference: (112.181018) => HOR

=======> diffeence : 0.065668
horx: 319.64 hory: 319.00 verx: 320.00 very: 319.81 difference: (112.386225) => VER

=======> diffeence : 0.416958
horx: 319.95 hory: 319.00 verx: 320.00 very: 319.97 difference: (112.307330) => VER

=======> diffeence : -71.782433
horx: 320.26 hory: 319.00 verx: 384.00 very: 285.97 difference: (112.998216) => HOR

=======> diffeence : -71.378059
horx: 320.57 hory: 319.00 verx: 384.00 very: 286.24 difference: (113.273688) => HOR

As seen in the output, rays hitting walls in sequence have unexpected behavior near the intersections, leading to inconsistencies in texture rendering.
How can I modify my calculations to ensure consistent and correct texture rendering for consecutive walls?

Edit the question to provide a [mre].
